# What in .htaccess redirect subdomain apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, debian

What I must to do, when I have got DNS to subdomain and when someone go to blog.example.com the website url is the same but the content is from the main page not from blog folder.

What I should to do? What must be in /var/www/blog/ in .htaccess if anything?

Please help!

Comment: little confused...  on blog.example.com you want it to point to something on that is on example.com?

Comment: No, on blog example.com i want a redirect from blog folder.

Comment: I still find what you say unclear...could you provide more details of what you mean?  you want blog.example.com to redirect to something like example.com/?something-else=blog ??

Comment: I want to make subdomain from folder /var/www/blog

Comment: ahh.. you need to add a virtualhost entry to your httpd.conf check here - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html -- is that what you mean?

Comment: Okay, I saw your other post related to this.  Try adding `Require all granted` inside of your `<Directory>` tags (this is only works for Apache 2.4),  you may also need to remove "Order allow,deny" and "allow from all".. also if you updated your dns, you shouldn't need to add anything to your hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule :

```
 RewriteEngine On

#if host is blog.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$
#then serve all requests from the Root folder.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [NC,L]
```

Replace **blog.example.com** with your subdomain in the http_host string.